# Woocommerce - Create a separate catalog by using woocommerce products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In my woocommerce products, I have products that are available for purchase, I also have hidden products which are not available for purchase

I would like to also create a catalog category page and individual catalog product pages programmatically using all products in woocommerce, which:
the catalog category page will list all products (hidden and non hidden) under that category and when clicked on that product, it will display just the product information with no add to cart option.

Please note I don't want to convert the woocommerce into catalog, I want to have both woocommerce shop and catelog options

Comment: You'll have to ask WooCommerce support about this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.